# Clean socket buffer?

Tags: c#, sockets, client, buffer

I'm developing a c# client/server application that uses TCP sockets to communicate. The server connects to an sql database and stores accounts.

My client can register normally. When a user logins, the server reads info from different tables and sends that info to the client in different messages.

Now what happens is this. When the server sends that info, the first message is fine, but the second message has the first in it's end.

What I think is that the client socket keeps the first message in it's buffer. So I tried to find a way to clean or flush the socket's buffer, but I couldn't find a solution on the internet. Can someone tell me if is this my real problem and if it's possible to clean a socket's buffer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix your message protocol so that it works.  If data is being duplicated, it's 99.999999% sure to be your code.

Comment: My crystal ball says: You're ignoring the return value of the [Socket.Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx) or [NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) method.

Comment: @dtb - could be, it has been known to happen:)

Comment: Ok, thanks to you all. My real problem was actually timing. The server was too fast for my client, giving no time for him to read the messages separately. Because of my breakpoints, it was making the first message perfect and the second wrong. I simply added a sleep before sending the second message and now it works. Anyway, thanks for answering me. :)

Comment: @user2858325 - if you think you've fixed the problem by adding a sleep() delay, you haven't.  You've just band-aided over it in such a way that it works in your test environment. It will come back to bite you later.  TCP streams cannot transfer messages longer than one byte.

Comment: This problem only shows up in the login part, the rest of the applications is working fine, and the timer solved it. You may be right or not.

Comment: @MartinJames *is* right. You haven't fixed it. Sleeps are entirely unnecessary in blocking network programming. They are literally a waste of time. Look again. Take the hint above about not ignoring the read count. Take it from people who know. Your bug remains, lurking.

Comment: I discovered my problem is not about the buffer. The server sends the messages too quick, and when the client reads, catches 2 or 3 messages together. With timers, I can slow down the server transmissions, so that the client has time to read each message correctly.

Comment: TCP does not provide the transmission of messages. It provides a bi-directional stream. You send data by writing it in chunks to the stream, and receive data by reading it in chunks from the stream. But the chunks that the sender sends are not necessarily the chunks that the receiver reads. **You have not fixed your problem.**

Comment: MartinJames is still right, as is @dtb. Slowing down the server isn't guaranteed to fix it. TCP can combine or split packets any way it likes. You have to write your receiving code accordingly. You can receive anything from 1 byte upwards. It's a byte-stream protocol, not a message protocol. Don't take this lightly. Your bug remains unfixed.